# Is there a difference between "слёзы" and "слезы"?

Tags: произношение, разница, буква-ё

I'm looking for the pronunciation of the word слезы (tears). On forvo.com both spellings [слезы](https://forvo.com/word/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B/#ru) and [слёзы](https://forvo.com/word/%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B7%D1%8B/#ru) are listed and pronounced differently. Is the meaning the same in both cases and how/why do they differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're pronounced exactly the same way because it's the exact same word. The usage of the letter "ё" from the very beginning of its existence (it [was](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%81_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)) introduced in the late 18th century) was quite controversial and almost never obligatory.

That leads to this double spelling. In some cases it eventually affected the way we pronounce some words (nobody says Рёрих nowadays. Another very famous example is "свекла"/"cвёкла"), but this never happened with "слёзы", which obeys the regular rules of pronouncing words with "ё" ("йо" at the beginning of a word; palatalization of preceding consonant plus "о" anywhere else).

Keep in mind, though, that the singular form, "слеза" is correct without "ё", the same, for instance, as with "звезда"/"звёзды".

Comment: Я не увидел ни единой слезы

Comment: @Elena that's singular and it mentioned in answer

Comment: @Elena, a namesake? Why does the site allow this phenomenon...

Comment: @Elena, probably the site 'thinks' that the identification = name + avatar. But the avatar is not visible in the comments and this can lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: The phrase "which are pronounced differently" in the question makes me think that we are dealing with genitive "слезы" here rather than е/ё interchanging.

Comment: @Alexander I suggest that by слёзы/слезы pronounced differently was meant exactly the fact that those are different spellings that seemingly supposed to be pronounced differently. Of course, only the author can clarify.

Comment: @shabunc this might be the case, but imho unlikely, because plural pronunciation "слезы" is very archaic now. On the other hand, singular genitive "слезы" is perfectly mainstream.

Comment: Alexander it's about spelling, not pronunciation (and to my knowledge it never was pronounced that way in plural)

Comment: @shabunc you are wrong, it was. The stress was on the first syllable. We have this form in Church-Slavonic texts.

Comment: @Elena well, I might be wrong, but in my knowledge **in Russian** it was never a case (and Church-Slavonic is a different language)

Comment: @shabunc ))))) never say never, I gave it as an example of where we can still hear this outdated phenomenon. Besides, we can find it in literature, but it takes time to find a quote.

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be traced through the question. 
[image]
It means, слез**ы** is the Genitive case singular,

and слёзы is the Nominative case plural. This word, as you can see from the previous answer, can be written without dots above е, but it retains the ё-pronunciation.